# Why `using System.Linq` adds functionality to other libraries

Tags: c#, linq

I've been using C# for some years now but I've been a little too lazy to learn about all the new features of it as they are introduced. Perhaps one of major features would be `Linq`, which I never understood its benefits. But never mind  that, what I'm interested in right now is a black magic that happens when the `using System.Linq` statement is added to a file.

Recently I've been using `MongoDB` in `C#` and I wanted to retrieve a single document out of database. Here's how it is done:

```
var cursor = colletion.FindAs<Entity>(query).SetLimit(1);
var en = cursor.Single<Entity>();
```

The above code extracts one single document of type `Entity` out of a collection. The part that amazes me is that the `Single` method of cursor is recognized only when the `using System.Linq` is added to the file. How is that possible?

Comment: Google 'Extension methods'. There's no magic involved - you can even write your own! :)

Comment: try removing using system.linq , count methods available when you write cursor.       now add using system.linq and see the count ...its a magic ...

Comment: I wouldn't say it is new. It was introduced in VS2008 with .Net 3.5, so it's at least 5 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Single` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Extension methods are static methods within static classes and their first input parameter are marked with the `this` keyword. Example:

```
namespace System.Linq 
{
    public static class Enumerable
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Single<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When the compiler sees `a.Single()` where `a` is an `IEnumerable<T>`  and cannot find such a method on that object, it will search for an extension method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` in its first parameter.

In order for this resolution to work, the static class that exposes the extension method `Enumerable` needs to be *within scope*, which you bring in scope by importing the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

From [msdn extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type.
>
> The most common extension methods are the LINQ standard query
>   operators that add query functionality to the existing
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable types. To use the standard
>   query operators, first bring them into scope with a using System.Linq
>   directive. Then any type that implements IEnumerable appears to
>   have instance methods such as GroupBy, OrderBy, Average, and so on.
>   You can see these additional methods in IntelliSense statement
>   completion when you type "dot" after an instance of an IEnumerable
>   type such as List or Array.